# Azure Cloud Service definition xml datatype error

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment

I can't specify "Let's Encrypt . . " in Azure Cloud definition for certificate name. I need to specify intermediate certificate name, can't change the name.

Wrong:

```
<Certificate name="Let's Encrypt Authority X3"
```

Right:

```
<Certificate name="Lets Encrypt Authority X3"
```

Because ServiceDefinition:NamedElementNameString doesn’t allow apostrophe(').
Also I have tried:

```
<Certificate name="Let&apos;s Encrypt Authority X3"
```

Adding SSL cert as per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: I end up skipping this. As there was no need to add the intermediate cert.